# File access between mcu and PC through rs232 communication

Tags: c, windows, serial-port, embedded, microcontroller

I'm using a LPC178 development board and I want to read a file present on a Windows PC. My dev board only has a RS2323 interface to communicate with.

How can I go about transferring the file from my PC to my MCU using a RS232 (serial) link? I found a [reference](https://www.xanthium.in/Serial-Port-Programming-using-Win32-API) which explains how to transfer data between a MCU and PC but it isn't about file transfers.

Comment: "How do I do my whole project" is far too broad a topic. The MCU most likely doesn't care about files, instead you should provide it with the meaningful data from a PC program. You need to create a PC program, a RS-232 protocol and the firmware side.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no easy solution for this like calling something like "copy" or "fopen" over RS232. I would be happy to be proven wrong here.

The fastest solution might be to write a little programm running on your Windows Host, which listens to your RS232 communication and pipes your communication into/out of the file based on your communication protocol. This can be done with standard file operations in the language of your choice, for example C, C++ or Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one of the oldest in the book. How do you transfer files without fancy operating system abstractions. For RS232 (or any other serial method) there exists many file transfer protocols.

One of them is [kermit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_(protocol)). This is a protocol from 1981 and can transfer binary and text files. It is [able to be embedded in a micrcontroller](http://www.kermitproject.org/ek.html) and there exists programs to transfer/receive using kermit.

[*alternative old site for reference*](ftp://www.columbia.edu/kermit/public_html/old/true-embedding.html)

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest case you would use a file transfer protocol such as XMODEM, YMODEM, ZMODEM or Kermit - these protocols were designed in the days before networking and the Internet were ubiquitous and deal with simple point-to-point transfers between two computers.  They are supported bu most terminal emulator tools such as TeraTerm Pro or PuTTY so no specific PC software need be written, just the microcontroller end.

A more complex but flexible solution is to implement a TCP/IP stack and a PPP driver, and an FTP application layer - probabaly only practical if using a third-party TCP/IP stack and application layer.  You can then use any FTP client for the PC end, so again no PC software required.  While this may be overkill if all you need to do is transfer files, it has the advantage of allowing you to use the the single serial port concurrently for other data streams and application protocols such as Telnet.  The disadvantage perhaps is that while Windows does support PPP it is buried within the dial-up networking and to be frank a pain to get working.

Answer (score 0):

Very first step you have to do is ensure serial communication is working fine.

1. Send a byte continuously from mcu to PC and display it on some io console (for example: HyperTerminal, Dock light )
2. Receive a byte to mcu from PC and echo it back to PC.

Once you are sure that serial communication is working fine then select some file transfer protocol and implement it.

While you can select any of the available protocols or write your own protocol and implement it.
For purpose of discussion i select Xmodem protocol.
If you consider some other protocol you may stop reading answer here.

XMODEM is a simple file transfer protocol.
Refer http://web.mit.edu/6.115/www/amulet/xmodem.htm for detailed information.
You may implement Xmodem mcu side by reading protocol. Or may consider using open source also ( if available )

PC side i prefer to use HyperTerminal io console as it is compatible with Xmodem.
In HyperTerminal all that i have to do is configure settings and select file for transfer to mcu.
Now transfer any file to mcu using Xmodem protocol from PC.

What you do with received file in mcu is up to you :  )